# C structs will this work?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

With the fwrite, I'm writing the whole structs? w.e is in f1 and f2? Any help would be appreciated

```
typedef struct {
    int field1;
    int field2;
}mystruct;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    int size=2;
    mystruct structarray [size];
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        structarray[i]=calloc(1,sizeof(mystruct));
    }

    FILE *F1;
    if (fopen("structfile","wt")==NULL){
        err_sys("cannot be opened");
    }

     i=0;
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        structarray[i].field1=i;
    }

    fwrite(structarray[0].field1,sizeof(mystruct),size,F1);
    fclose(F1);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is not your problem, but you are already allocating the two `mystruct` structures statically -- you don't need to call `calloc` to allocate any more on the heap.

Comment: I'd probably open the file with a "wb" to write binary, since you aren't doing any fprintf formatted printing.  BTW, it's okay to write/read binary data, which is what it looks like you are doing.  Just don't try to read the binary data in as "text" because there could be 0 values in your binary data which will confuse the std C string functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, your approach will work.  However, there are a few problems with your code:

(1) `structarray` is declared as an automatic variable (allocated on the stack).  There's no reason to call `calloc()` for each array element; the array is already fully allocated.  Perhaps you meant to initialize the array elements (e.g., `memset()`, etc.).

(2) `fopen()` returns the pointer to the file that was opened, but you are not assigning the return value to `F1`.  As a result, `F1` remains uninitialized, so the call to `fwrite()` isn't going to work.

(3) If your intention is to save the full array of structures to the file (as opposed to specific elements), change your call to `fwrite()` as follows:

```
fwrite(structarray, sizeof(mystruct), size, F1);
```

(4) Always check the return value from `fwrite()` to make sure it succeeded.

Comment: Always check the value of `fwrite` but also of `fclose`. For example in case of a disk full condition you may get `fwrite` to succeed (it's just writing in buffers) and `fclose` to fail.

Comment: "Conceptually, your approach will work" -- No, it's undefined behavior ... attempting to convert the value of `structarray[0].field1` into a pointer.

Comment: @6502 fclose will copy the in-memory stdio buffer to the kernel's disk buffer, but that won't detect disk full unless you've told the system to do synchronous writes.

Answer (score 1):

`structarray[0].field1` is an `int`, but the first argument of `fwrite` is `void*`.  Use

```
fwrite(structarray, sizeof(mystruct), size, F1);
```

or, I prefer

```
fwrite(structarray, sizeof *structarray, size, F1);
```

because it isn't coupled to the type of `structarray` and reducing coupling is a good thing.  You could even just do

```
fwrite(structarray, sizeof structarray, 1, F1);
```

as long as `structarray` is truly an array and not a pointer.

You should check the return value of `fwrite`. And compile with the warning level set high ... the compiler should warn you about your attempt to pass an `int` to `fwrite`, as well as

```
structarray[i]=calloc(1,sizeof(mystruct));
```

which isn't legit ... `structarray[i]` is a `mystruct` but `calloc` returns a pointer. See  aardvarkk's comment under your question. It should also tell you that you used F1 without ever setting it.